# How to add control to the beginning of the collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example;

`panel1.Controls.Add(myControl);` add to end of the collection.

Is there a way to add to the beginning of the collection without replacing the one at the beginning?

`panel1.Controls.AddAt(0, myControl)` replaces the control at 0.

**update**

actually it seems to work and not replace it. i might have gotten it wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`ControlCollection.SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) method.

> Sets the index of the specified child control in the collection to the
>   specified index value.

---

> When `SetChildIndex` is called, the `Control` referred to by the child
>   parameter is moved to the position specified by newIndex and the other
>   `Control` references in the `Control.ControlCollection` are reordered to
>   accommodate the move.

Comment: This is true, but SetChildIndex causes the parent control to re-layout, causing a visual shuffling.  Calling Control::SuspendLayout on the parent control does not prevent this.  It would be better to have a way to insert at the beginning of the list whereas SetChildIndex requires it to be added first and then moved, both operations causing a layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List<Literal> persistControls = new List<Literal>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
     display();           
}

protected void commentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal myComment = new Literal();
    myComment.Text = "<p>" + commentBox.Text + "</p><br />";
    commentPanel.Controls.Add(myComment);
    persistControls.Insert(0,myComment);
    Session["persistControls"] = persistControls; 
    display();
}
void display()
{
    // if you already have some literal populated
    if (Session["persistControls"] != null)
    {
        // pull them out of the session
        persistControls = (List<Literal>)Session["persistControls"];
        foreach (Literal ltrls in persistControls)
            commentPanel.Controls.Add(ltrls); // and push them back into the page
    }
}
```